# If $X$ is compact and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a dense continuous injection, then $f$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I found this: 
Let $X$ be a compact space and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous injection. Let $f(X)$ be dense in $Y$. 
Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

So, my question is: is it possible to prove that? I tried proving it and I couldn't, since Y is not necessarily a Hausdorff space.

The Hausdorff-condition is needed when proving that f is a closed mapping, but I guess you could do it some other way.

Comment: Hausdorff is needed. Take $Y=X$ with the trivial topology and consider the identity map from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Please consider changing the title, to be more informative.

Comment: Note that $f(X)$ is compact and thus closed in $Y$ under the assumption that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Together with being dense it implies that $f(X)=Y$. With that you apply the classical "continuous bijection from a compact space" argument.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above by @DavidMitra.*

---

It is necessary that $Y$ is Hausdorff. For a counterexample when $Y$ is not Hausdorff, let $Y$ be the set $X$ equipped with the trivial topology. Assume that the topology on $X$ is not the trivial topology. Then, the identity map from $X$ to $Y$ is injective, continuous, and the image is dense in $Y$ (in fact it is all of $Y$). However, $f$ is not a homeomorphism.